# Python adding too much rows to excel document

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to make application that adds tarantula species to my excel document. I'm doing it with openpyxl and when i'm adding the second name to B column it adds that name 2 times instead of 1. Here is the code

```
import openpyxl
import random
import time
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx") 

ws = wb.active

def InsertGenus (genus):
    for cellA in ws["A"]:
        if cellA.value is None:
            break
        else:
            print("Empty")
            ws["A"+str(cellA.row + 1)] = genus



def InsertSpecies (species):
    for cellB in ws["B"]:
        if cellB.value is None:
            break
        else:
            print("Empty")
            ws["B"+str(cellB.row + 1)] = species

genus = input("Enter tarantula genus: ")
InsertGenus(genus)
species = input("Enter tarantula species: ")
InsertSpecies(species)


wb.save("sample.xlsx")

input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code a bit to one function and used max_row+2 to cover the base case with the empty cell as well. Hope that this help.

```
import openpyxl
import random
import time
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx") 

ws = wb.active

def InsertTarantula (genus, species):
    for row in range(1, ws.max_row+2):
        if ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value == None and ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value == None:
            #print(ws.cell(row=row, column=1).coordinate, ws.cell(row=row, column=2).coordinate)
            ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value = genus
            ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = species
            break

genus = input("Enter tarantula genus: ")
species = input("Enter tarantula species: ")
InsertTarantula(genus, species)

wb.save("sample.xlsx")

input("Press any key to exit...")
```